# iOS - How to update an app after transfert

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

First, sorry for my bad english. :(

I have a question about [app transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) on Apple Store.

After a transfert, What is the good way (process) to update this app (step by step) ?

Do we need use the old app id, or make a new app id ? For the update who must prepare the app (certificate, provisionning, etc.)  ? the old or new account ? Which account must upload the app ? the old or the new ?

I don't find a doc about this, only some simple (but not complete) response like : 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122400/how-do-i-upload-a-new-version-of-an-app-after-an-app-transfer

Edit :

i'm using Adobe Air for packaging the ipa.

I have no access to the new account. Only the old with certificate and the first bundle id of the app.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new account and hence the provisioning profile/cert will be from new account. (If you are using xcode 8, you don't even need to manually do this. Just enter you new account details in xcode and set the xcode to automatically manage signing. It will take care of provisioning profile and cert.) And app should be uploaded from new account.

Comment: Thx for the response. i don't use Xcode. I use Adobe Air packaging. So i need the login informations from the new account ? There are no solution to update the app on new account with only the old account ?

Comment: I recently did an update to transferred app but with new account and it went fine. Not aware if you can use old account.( I am assuming you won't be able to use old account - thats what the transfer would mean)